# PR preview analysis causes waitForQualityGate to fail

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Today i encountered an anomaly when setting up a Jenkins pipeline script which checks both the quality gate
and annotates pull requests with any new issues.

Our setup contains of:

- SonarQube 6.2
- BitBucket Stash
- Jenkins 2 (with 2 slaves)
- AmadeusITGroup stash plugin

Part of the pipeline script:

```
node(node_label) {
    stage("SonarQube analysis") {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
            def sonarQubeCommand = "org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar " +
                    "-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar-url " +
                    "-Dsonar.login=sonarqube " +
                    "-Dsonar.password=token " +
                    "-Dsonar.language=java " +
                    "-Dsonar.sources=. " +
                    "-Dsonar.inclusions=**/src/main/java/**/*"
            if (pr.id != '') {
                sonarQubeCommand = sonarQubeCommand +
                        " -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview" +
                        " -Dsonar.stash.notification=true " +
                        " -Dsonar.stash.project=" + pr.project_key +
                        " -Dsonar.stash.repository=" + pr.repository_slug +
                        " -Dsonar.stash.pullrequest.id=" + pr.id +
                        " -Dsonar.stash.password=token"
            }
            pipeline.mvn(sonarQubeCommand)
        }
    }
}

stage("Check Quality Gate") {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
        def qg = waitForQualityGate()
        waitUntil {
            // Sometimes an analysis will get the status PENDING meaning it still needs to be analysed.
            if (qg.status == 'PENDING') {
                qg = waitForQualityGate()
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        node(node_label) {
            if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                bitbucket.comment(pr, "_${env.JOB_NAME}#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}:_ **[&#10006; BUILD FAILURE](${build_url})**")
                bitbucket.approve(pr, false)
                pipeline.cleanWorkspace()
                error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
            } else {
                bitbucket.comment(pr, "_${env.JOB_NAME}#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}:_ **[&#10004; BUILD SUCCESS](${build_url})**")
                bitbucket.approve(pr, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw: Without the waitUntil the pipeline failed because the task status was PENDING in SonarQube.
So the example in the SonarSource blog didn't quite work for me.

Now for the details how this pipeline fails:

When using sonar.analysis.mode=preview as parameter on the maven command
the jenkins job log will not contain the SonarQube analysis task id.
This will result in a failure in the pipeline script on command waitForQualityGate.
The message reads: 
Unable to get SonarQube task id and/or server name. Please use the 'withSonarQubeEnv' wrapper to run your analysis.

As soon as i remove the sonar.analysis.mode=preview parameter the jenkins log reads a line like:`[INFO] More about the report processing at https://sonar-url/api/ce/task?id=AVyHXjcsesZZZhqzzCSf`

This line makes the waitForQualityGate command succeed normally.
However, this has an unwanted side effect besides the polution of the project in SonarQube with PR results.
The side effect is that when an issue was added in the pull request this won't be reported on the pull request in stash.
It always reports zero new issues and this is clearly wrong.
As it's not a preview analysis anymore i can see the new issue on the SonarQube server.

So somehow i have to make a choice now between having pull requests annotated with new issues or
checking the quality gate.
Obviously i would like to do both.
I have chosen to let pull request annotation work properly and skip the check on the quality gate for now.

Question remains am i doing something wrong here or do i have to wait for new versions of scanner and/or stash plugin to have this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

At sonar's server go to:

> *Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Webhooks*:
>
> **Name**: Jenkins or something like that
>
> **URL**:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/sonarqube-webhook/

Where, URL is Jenkins host.

**Cause**:

By default webkooks on sonar are https, and my jenkins was working over http.